# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation - matlab

Tags: matlab, storage, ram

I am using Matlab 2014a under Windows7. I am running a loop that reads very big xlsx files (~40MB each). After I am done with a file I use 'clear' in order to free the memory taken by reading the file. The thing is that every once in a while the script is stops and giving me an error message:

> > Error using xlsread (line 247)
> >     Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

I want to emphasis that after each time I am finishing with a file I clear all the variables, so each iteration only one file is loaded. If I restart Matlab the script may work again - making me believe that some how 'clear' command doesn't free all the memory that was allocated. is there a way to really free the memory that once was allocated in matlab?
thank you very much
Ariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If restarting Matlab is not an option, the "pack" function should help. Otherwise you could also use matlab without the gui and write a shell script that starts and matlab for each file.